# Enabling and disabling form elements in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

(I'm quite new to React, so apologies if this seems like a silly question).

I have a React control, where I simply want to be able to select a button, and have that button disabled and another one enabled; for example:

```
class MyControl extends Component<IMyControlProps> {

... 

    public render() {
        var isRunning = false;

        return (
            <Button name="btnStart" disabled={isRunning} onClick={ () => { 
                isRunning = true;
                this.props.RunningFunc;                 
            }}>Start Running</Button>
            <Button name="btnStop" disabled={!isRunning} onClick={ () => {
                isRunning = false;
                this.props.StopRunningFunc!
            }}>Stop!</Button>
 ...
```

However, pressing the start button has no effect on the enabled state of the stop button.  Is there a method or function that needs to be called to force a refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to migrate the isRunning to state. When you update the state the render function will invoked and your gui updates.

```
state = {isRunning: false};

public render() {
    return (
        <Button name="btnStart" disabled={this.state.isRunning} onClick={ () => { 
            this.setState({isRunning:true});
            this.props.RunningFunc;                 
        }}>Start Running</Button>
        <Button name="btnStop" disabled={!this.state.isRunning} onClick={ () => {
            this.setState({isRunning:false});
            this.props.StopRunningFunc;
        }}>Stop!</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a state variable!

Like this:

```
return (
            <Button name="btnStart" disabled={this.state.isRunning} onClick={ () => { 
                this.setState({ isRunning: true });
                this.props.RunningFunc;                 
            }}>Start Running</Button>
            <Button name="btnStop" disabled={!this.state.isRunning} onClick={ () => {
                this.setState({ isRunning: false });
                this.props.StopRunningFunc!
            }}>Stop!</Button>
```